# Extract top 100 and bottom 100 values in R

Tags: r

I am new in R script, here is my simple problem,
how to extract top 100 and bottom 100 values from a file in single command.

```
top<- head(xdata, 100)

bottom <- head(xdata, 100)
```

but I want in single command

like this...

```
both <- head(xdata, 100) +  head(xdata, 100)
```

Thanks

Comment: If this is a data frame then `rbind(head(xdata, 100), tail(xdata, 100))`. If it's a vector use `c()` instead of `rbind()`.

Comment: In case you just want to view to top+bottom n rows in the console, you might want to use the `data.table` package, which does that by default. E.g. `print(xdata, topn = 100)`

Comment: Thanks Gregor and LukeA .......                                                          c(head(xdata, 100), tail(xdata, 100))            is working....

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way, if *n* is the length of your data vector.

```
 # Fake data
 n <- 10^6
 xdata <- runif(n)

 # Get first 100 and last 100 in vector
 v <- xdata[c(1:100, (n-99):n)]
```

You can also use `tail` as someone mentioned in the comments, but it is more efficient to index as I did above. To demonstrate this:

```
# Load microbenchmark package to compare computation speed
library(microbenchmark)
library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark( "direct index" = xdata[c(1:100, (n-99):n)], 
            "head/tail" = c(head(xdata, 100), tail(xdata, 100)))
print(m)
#Unit: microseconds
#     expr      min     lq     mean   median  uq     max      neval
#direct index  2.814  3.028  3.54298  3.422  3.6950  16.255    100
#head/tail     29.239 30.691 34.61539 31.628 33.0045 110.648   100
```

Indexing is 6.5X faster on my machine.

Comment: compare on bigger samples though, e.g. 10^6

Comment: I still get better performance from indexing. If you can provide an example where using `head` and `tail` work better, I'd be curious to see it...

Comment: That was not my point. There is no need to worry about performance on 1000 records. Quite often solutions work better on small samples but scale badly.